# Allow port 25 on client owned ip address range

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Now that Azure supports the BYOIP option, does it mean that a client is allowed to generate outbound SMTP connection (port 25) from a machine using their custom ip resources?

Or is there any plan to allow this option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

***Azure supports the BYOIP:***

Azure supports the BYOIP options [To Bring your own IP addresses (BYOIP) to Azure with Custom IP Prefix](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/bring-your-own-ip-addresses-byoip-to-azure-with-custom-ip-prefix/) here the onboarded ips interact with private IPs and reach external destination to bring your own Ip address Azure is currently available in all regions and have minimum size upto (256 IP addresses and there is no charge for hosting

***Client is allowed to generate outbound SMTP connection (port 25) from a machine :***

- If you are setting email client with SMTP usually port 25 is not recommended because its commonly used to send span, Residential ISPs & cloud providers are block port 25 and you need to get a VPS from organization which allows port 25
- In case it was blocked you need to send request to block removed go to the **Cannot send email (SMTP-Port 25)** section of the **Diagnose and Solve problem** in the Azure Virtual Network

***Plan to allow this option :***

- You can typically connect through TCP port 587 as the default modern web it has minimum possibilities that third-party email providers reject messages

*Microsoft cannot assurance email providers will acknowledge inbound email from your virtual machine if azure allow port 25*

Please check this [So thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c1b528b-dc68-4030-b29a-09ce685c570b/open-ports-25587-in-order-to-send-email-from-an-azure-vm?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows) by **Micah McKittrick** which worked on the similar thread

For your Reference :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivit